# Dynamically created Buttons are getting added after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

More buttons are dynamically created and added in div. My page has name and password field and submit button. Once I enter the value and click the submit button set of buttons will be created. When I do the refresh on the page I dont see any buttons in the page.But after refresh I enter the details and submit the form multiple buttons are created for example instead of 10 button 40 buttons are created.

```
if(($('#valuecheck').val())!="1")
                            {
                            for (i in so_values) {
                                var new_Button = $('<div class="col-md-2 top-space-20"><input type="button" class="btn" value="' + so_values[i]+'"></div>');
                                elements.push(new_Button);                                                                              
                            }

                            console.log("value check adding 1 wiht the value" + $('#valuecheck').val());
                            }

                            console.log("Elements length" + elements.length);                                
                        }
                    } 
                    if(($('#valuecheck').val())!="1")
                        {                                           
                    $("#resultDiv").html(msg);
                    if (elements!="" &&  elements.length > 0){

                        $("#resultDiv").append(elements);
                        $('#valuecheck').val("1");
```

Comment: There isn't enough code here to offer any help. What is so_values?

Comment: so_values ,I am fetching it from the backend.It's list of dictionaries and I am trying to add the buttons for each so_values.

Comment: Can you edit your question with more code. Show an example of what `so_values` looks like. Plus, the HTML structure that you're trying to update.